# Why is there a sizeof... operator in C++0x?

Tags: c++, language-design, c++11

I saw that @GMan implemented [a version of `sizeof...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770474/how-to-find-the-length-of-a-parameter-pack/2770496#2770496) for variadic templates which (as far as I can tell) is equivalent to the built in `sizeof...`. Doesn't this go against the second design principle: [*prefer libraries to language extensions*](http://public.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Variadic Templates (Revision 3)
(N2080=06-0150)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2080.pdf), page 6:

> Although not strictly necessary (we can implement `count` without this feature), **checking the length of a parameter pack is a common operation that deserves a simple syntax**. Moreover, this operation may become necessary for type-checking reasons when variadic templates are combined with concepts; see Section 3.3.

(Section 3.3 talks about concepts which is irrelevant now.)

Comment: `sizeof...` can also be applied equally well to template and function parameter packs. So `sizeof...(T)` and `sizeof...(t)` work equally well. A library based solution would work either with template or function parameter packs but not with both, i believe. Because one expansion produces a sequence of types, and the other expansion produces a sequence of expressions. Maybe writing it as `template<size_t...> struct count;` and then passing the pack as `count<sizeof(T)...>` could work. Since `sizeof` can handle both types and expressions that would seem to work, but it's clearly uglier :)

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof...` is just sugar, I think.

`sizeof` is indeed core to the language as is `...`, and although a `countof` function could exist we already have `sizeof` and `...` reserved so we might as well make it convenient to get the count that way.

Contrarily, if `sizeof` and `...` weren't reserved, the idea of adding such a thing would have probably failed because new keywords tend to be frowned upon. (The less the better.)