# sizeof variadic template (sum of sizeof of all elements)

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, sizeof, variadic-templates

Considering the following function :

```
template<typename... List> 
inline unsigned int myFunction(const List&... list)
{
    return /* SOMETHING */; 
}
```

What is the most simple thing to put instead of `/* SOMETHING */` in order to return the sum of `sizeof` all arguments ?

For example `myFunction(int, char, double) = 4+1+8 = 13`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
unsigned myFunction() {return 0;}

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
unsigned myFunction(const Head & head, const Tail &... tail) {
    return sizeof head + myFunction(tail...);
}
```

Comment: Smart (+1) - with `inline` will be even smarter.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: `inline` as an optimization thing, is just a hint. Nothing more. Personally I value code clarity far more than that hinting, and then `inline` should better be reserved for its one guaranteed effect, namely its ODR effect.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Yes, if you need to define the non-template overload in a header file, then it will need to be `inline`. That's rather irrelevant to the question, though.

Comment: It works perfectly as a compile time `constexpr` in gcc, clang and VS12. I wonder why there's no standard library support for this.

Answer (score 17):

In C++17, use a fold expression:

```
template<typename... List> 
inline constexpr unsigned int myFunction(const List&... list)
{
    return (0 + ... + sizeof(List));
}
```

Comment: Best option for C++17 and above.

Answer (score 4):

Based off of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628364/count-of-parameters-in-a-parameter-pack-is-there-a-c0x-std-lib-function-for-t#comment3816253_3628564) and the following comments on the question, you could use this (note: completely untested)

```
std::initializer_list<std::size_t> sizeList = {sizeof(List)...}; //sizeList should be std::initializer_list, according to the comments I linked to
return std::accumulate(sizeList.begin(), sizeList.end(), 0);
```

Comment: This begs the interesting question: will this be statically computed (all the way down) ?

Comment: I do not think this will be statically computed unless someone made a constexpr version of std::accumulate, or if you happen to have a super optimizing compiler, but I have no idea about if any compiler will optimize that much.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a version of Clang with `std::initializer_list` :/

Answer (score 3):

Two years late but an alternative solution guaranteed to be computed by the compiler (if you don't mind the different syntax):

```
template < typename ... Types >
struct SizeOf;

template < typename TFirst >
struct SizeOf < TFirst >
{
    static constexpr auto Value = (sizeof(TFirst));
};

template < typename TFirst, typename ... TRemaining >
struct SizeOf < TFirst, TRemaining ... >
{
    static constexpr auto Value = (sizeof(TFirst) + SizeOf<TRemaining...>::Value);
};
```

Used as `constexpr std::size_t size = SizeOf<int, char, double>::Value; // 4 + 1 + 8 = 13`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template way:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
class PPackSizeOf
{
  public:
  static const unsigned int size = sizeof(T) + PPackSizeOf<Ts...>::size;
};


template<typename T>
class PPackSizeOf<T>
{
  public:
  static const unsigned int size = sizeof(T);
};

template<typename ...Ts>
class FixedSizeBlock
{
   private:
      char block[PPackSizeOf<Ts...>::size];
   public:

};

int main( )
{
  FixedSizeBlock<char,long> b;
  std::cout << sizeof(b) << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I've just found that :

```
template<typename... List> 
inline unsigned int myFunction(const List&... list)
{
    return sizeof(std::make_tuple(list...)); 
}
```

But :

1) Do I have the guarantee that the result will always be the same on all compilers ?

2) Do the make_tuple will make and overhead at compile-time ?

Comment: This does not compute the sum of the sizes. You do have a guarantee that the size of the tuple is greater than or equal to the sum of the sizes.

Comment: An implementation is allowed to do what they want. Perhaps more pragmatically, remember that the only guarantee on the size of something like `struct { int i; double j; };` is that it's at least `sizeof(int) + sizeof(double)`, but it can be larger.

Comment: @Vincent - because of struct padding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c

Comment: @LucDanton Actually, not even that, if you have empty types.