# How to map structure to char proper method in C++

Tags: c++, networking, struct

In C I was used to work with char* to which I mapped some structure representing a network packet. Then I would just assign the packet parameters and send via network:

*UPDATED* - I forget to add that I have some payload

```
struct packet {
   uint64_t id __attribute__((packed)); 
   uint64_t something __attribute__((packed));
   short flags __attribute__((packed));
   // here follows payload with variable length
};
...
char *payload = get_payload();
size_t payload_size = get_payload_size();//doesnt matter how
char *data = malloc(sizeof(struct packet)+payload_size);
struct packet *pkt = (struct packet *)data;
pkt->id = 123;
pkt->something = get_something();
pkt->flags = FLAG | FLAG2;
memcpy(data+sizeof(struct packet), payload, payload_size);
send(data, sizeof(struct packet)+payload_size);
```

Now I would like to implement this with some nice C++ features (if there are any which could do this in better way)
Best change I can do in C++ is to use new instead of malloc.

```
char *data = new char[sizeof(struct packet)];//rest is same
```

Ok this is called object serialization.. I ve found couple of examples always using boost which I cannot use.. isnt there a native way in C++ to acomplish this?

Comment: What you are asking about is generally known as "object serialization". Try googling or seraching SO for "C++ object serialization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to create a `char*` and an `pkt*`.  You create and send an object like:

```
packet pkt;  // create automatic object
pkt.id = 123;
pkt.something = get_something();
pktflags = FLAG | FLAG2;
// here we cast the address of pkt to a char* so we can send it
send(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pkt), sizeof(packet));
```

Edit:

Since the question was updated to have a payload added to the end of the `struct` data you are going to have to use the same method that you did in C.  When you `new` up the pointer the syntax would be

```
char * data = new char[sizeof(packet) + payload_size];
```

Also the `struct` keyword is not required in C++ when using the `struct` like in C.  You can just use it by name.

Comment: thanks, I like your solution, but I forgot to add that I am using payload after the packet.. sorry for changing the question. will the "reinterpret_cast way" work if the packet would contain for example char * to the payload?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the way your original code depends on a non-standard extension `__attribute__((packed))`. Since there is no standard way to require that a `struct` has no padding at all, the only standard compliant way to copy a struct into a buffer is to copy each member individually.

That inspired me to write a c++11 helper to copy a variadic number of variables into a `char` array. And to help using that, a helper to count the total size of those variables (that was already done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12666815/2079303)). Using these helpers, you can easily copy the members of a `struct` into a buffer without requiring the `struct` to be packed.

```
// variadic sizeof
// mostly same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/12666815/2079303
constexpr std::size_t sizeof_all() {
    return 0;
}
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
constexpr std::size_t sizeof_all(const Head& head, const Tail&... tail) {
    return sizeof head + sizeof_all(tail...);
}

// variadic memcpy
void memcpy_all(char*) {}
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
void memcpy_all(char* out, const Head& head, const Tail&... tail) {
    auto offset = sizeof head;
    std::memcpy(out, &head, offset);
    memcpy_all(out + offset, tail...);
}

// to use
packet p;
std::size_t buffer_size = sizeof_all(p.id, p.something, p.flags) + payload_size;
char* data = new char[buffer_size];
memcpy_all(data, p.id, p.something, p.flags);
```

Now, you only need to concern yourself with endianness.