# Adjust array inside struct according to parameter pack length (passed into constructor)

Tags: c++, stdarray, parameter-pack

I want to create a constexpr struct which holds a number of states in an array, represented by `state_type_t`. The struct should be created dynamically via a parameter pack. My problem is that I don't know the size of the array holding the states as I would have to be aware of the number of arguments in the parameter pack... Is there a way around this (C++11)?

```
template<int S>
struct state_collection
{
    state_collection(state_type_t... Args) : states_(Args...) const noexcept {

    }

    std::array<state_type_t, S> states_; // <-- how big is S? How to derive S from parameter pack size?
};

struct region
{
    constexpr state_collection req_;
    constexpr state_collection act_;
};


region( { .req_{LOCAL_STATE_A, LOCAL_STATE_B}, .act_{} } );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the length of a parameter pack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770474/how-to-find-the-length-of-a-parameter-pack)

Comment: @cigien: No, unfortunately not because how would I use sizeof...(Args) in this case? Args is only known inside the constructor.

Comment: Are you sure you're using C++11? You have `.req_` and `.act_`, which look like designated initializers, which is only available from C++20. Are you using some GCC extensions by any chance?

Comment: @cigien: Don't know I just ported some C code and it worked as well. It also works out of the box on godbolt. Yes I'm using g++. But what you say doesn't sound particularly portable. Any alternative?

Comment: @cigien: Sorry I didn't mention: Yes I'm using C++11

Comment: @glades: I'm pretty sure that cigien is right - this is definitely not valid C++11 code. And this critically matters for the answer. A C++20 answer can use Class Template Argument Deduction to deduce `S` , but that's not in C++11.

Comment: @MSalters: You're right that it isn't valid C++11 code. But at the time I didn't even think about it because apparently g++ supports it anyway (probably because it makes C99 ports easier).